# how to stop a loop when a a value is < 0 in python

Tags: python, django, for-loop

how can i stop my loop if `prod_Available < 0` (negative value) and returns `status = 0` else it returns `status = 1`?. Is it possible that when my loop encounters `prod_Available < 0` it will stop looping and returns `status = 0`.?

here is my code :

```
   def get_hotel_sum_quantity(self, product_id, checkin_date, checkout_date, quantity):
        check_in = datetime.datetime.strptime(checkin_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        check_in = check_in.date()
        start_date = check_in.day

        check_out = datetime.datetime.strptime(checkout_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        check_out = check_out.date()
        end_date = check_out.day

        prod = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        prod_Available = 0
        array = []
        for x in range(start_date,end_date + 1):
            x = x - start_date
            delta = datetime.timedelta(days=x)
            all_date = check_in + delta
            sumOfQuantity = HotelCheck.objects.filter(date_booked=all_date, product=prod).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))['quantity__sum']
            if sumOfQuantity == None:
                sumOfQuantity = 0
            prod_Available = prod.quantity - sumOfQuantity
            prod_Available = float(prod_Available) - float(quantity)

            if prod_Available < 0:
                status = 0
            else:
                status = 1
            data = {'available': prod_Available, 'status': status, 'sumquantity': sumOfQuantity, 'quanity': quantity}
            array.append(data)           
        return array
```

i have already returned all the value but it wont stop looping when `prod_Available < 0`
here is what i have done:

```
>>> from booking.models import *
>>> Hotel.objects.get_hotel_sum_quantity(3, '2011-12-21', '2011-12-24', 1)
[{'available': 1.0, 'status': 1, 'sumquantity': 8, 'quanity': 1}, {'available': 1.0, 'status': 1, 'sumquantity': 8, 'quanity': 1}, {'available': 1.0, 'status': 1, 'sumquantity': 8, 'quanity': 1}, {'available': 9.0, 'status': 1, 'sumquantity': 0, 'quanity': 1}]
>>> Hotel.objects.get_hotel_sum_quantity(3, '2011-12-21', '2011-12-24', 2)
[{'available': 0.0, 'status': 1, 'sumquantity': 8, 'quanity': 2}, {'available': 0.0, 'status': 1, 'sumquantity': 8, 'quanity': 2}, {'available': 0.0, 'status': 1, 'sumquantity': 8, 'quanity': 2}, {'available': 8.0, 'status': 1, 'sumquantity': 0, 'quanity': 2}]
>>> Hotel.objects.get_hotel_sum_quantity(3, '2011-12-21', '2011-12-24', 3)
[{'available': -1.0, 'status': 0, 'sumquantity': 8, 'quanity': 3}, {'available': -1.0, 'status': 0, 'sumquantity': 8, 'quanity': 3}, {'available': -1.0, 'status': 0, 'sumquantity': 8, 'quanity': 3}, {'available': 7.0, 'status': 1, 'sumquantity': 0, 'quanity': 3}]
>>>
```

can anyone can give me an idea about my situation?

thanks in advance

Comment: Use `if prodAvailable < 0: break;` instead of the existing loop. Instead of `status`, just use the value 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mayb you could use the [break](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement of python to stop your loop :

```
if prod_Available < 0:
    status = 0
else:
    status=1

data = {'available': prod_Available, 'status': status, 'sumquantity': sumOfQuantity, 'quanity': quantity}
array.append(data)         
if status == 0:
   break
```

then, when prod_available will be under 0, it will stop the loop and your method will continue execution (and return array in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for x in range(start_date,end_date + 1):      
    x = x - start_date
    ............
```

you should write:

```
for x in range(end_date -start_date + 1):      
    ............
```

But there are other points to improve.
Here's my proposition:

```
import datetime
from time import strptime

def get_hotel_sum_quantity(product_id, checkin_date, checkout_date, quantity):        
    check_in = datetime.date(*strptime(checkin_date, '%Y-%m-%d')[0:3])
    check_out = datetime.date(*strptime(checkout_date, '%Y-%m-%d')[0:3])

    prod = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    prod_Available = 0
    array = []

    all_date = check_in
    one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    for i in xrange(check_in.day,check_out.day + 1):

        sumOfQuantity = HotelCheck.objects.filter(date_booked=all_date, product=prod).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))['quantity__sum']
        if sumOfQuantity == None:
            sumOfQuantity = 0
        prod_Available = prod.quantity - sumOfQuantity
        prod_Available = float(prod_Available) - float(quantity)

        if prod_Available > 0:
            array.append({'available': prod_Available, 'status': 1, 'sumquantity': sumOfQuantity, 'quanity': quantity})
            all_date += one_day           
        else:
            return array
```

If you want an element {'available': -1.0, 'status': 0, 'sumquantity': 8, 'quanity': 3} to be included and displayed in the return, you do:

```
if prod_Available > 0:
    array.append({'available': prod_Available, 'status': 1, 'sumquantity': sumOfQuantity, 'quanity': quantity})
    all_date += one_day           
else:
    array.append({'available': prod_Available, 'status': 0, 'sumquantity': sumOfQuantity, 'quanity': quantity})
    return array
```

And I think that if we were knowing the code of HotelCheck.objects and Sum('quantity')) , we could improve also the part using them
(please, anybody speaking correct english: correct this sentence, there's something wrong with verb but I can't find the correct way)

.

### Edit 1

My code had some drawbacks, I improved it:

```
def get_hotel_sum_quantity(self,product_id, checkin_date, checkout_date, quantity,
                           daylta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)):

    all_date = datetime.date(*strptime(checkin_date, '%Y-%m-%d')[0:3])
    check_out_day = strptime(checkout_date, '%Y-%m-%d')[2]

    prod = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    prod_quant = prod.quantity

    array = []

    for i in xrange(all_date.day,check_out_day + 1):

        sumOfQuantity = HotelCheck.objects\
                        .filter(date_booked=all_date,product=prod)\
                        .aggregate(Sum('quantity'))['quantity__sum']

        if sumOfQuantity == None:  sumOfQuantity = 0
        prod_Available = float(prod_quant - sumOfQuantity) - float(quantity)

        if prod_Available > 0:
            array.append({'available': prod_Available, 'status': 1,
                          'sumquantity': sumOfQuantity, 'quantity': quantity})
            all_date += daylta
        else:
            break

    return array
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the break statement to stop the loop! Remark that the break statement breaks the execution of the loop where you call it,

otherwise, if you don't like break, you can manually set x out of the range, but then the code would be harder to be read.

You probably want to break the loop at the very end (do you want to append the data to the array even if status is 0?)

```
array.append(data)
if prod_Available < 0:
    break
```